# Comparing two objects that are the same in MbUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, equality, mbunit, gallio

From MBUnit I am trying to check if the values of two objects are the same using

```
Assert.AreSame(RawDataRow, result);
```

However I am getting the following fail:

```
Expected Value & Actual Value : {RawDataRow: CentreID = "CentreID1",
CentreLearnerRef = "CentreLearnerRef1",
ContactID = 1, DOB = 2010-05-05T00:00:00.0000000,
Email = "Email1", ErrorCodes = "ErrorCodes1",
ErrorDescription = "ErrorDescription1", FirstName = "FirstName1"}
```

Remark : Both values look the same when formatted but they are distinct instances.

I don't want to have to go through each property.  Can I do this from MbUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up building my own using Reflections

```
private bool PropertiesEqual<T>(T object1, T object2)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection object2Properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(object1);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor object1Property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(object2))
            {
                PropertyDescriptor object2Property = object2Properties.Find(object1Property.Name, true);

                if (object2Property != null)
                {
                    object object1Value = object1Property.GetValue(object1);
                    object object2Value = object2Property.GetValue(object2);

                    if ((object1Value == null && object2Value != null) || (object1Value != null && object2Value == null))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (object1Value != null && object2Value != null)
                    {
                        if (!object1Value.Equals(object2Value))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It will work fine. But MbUnit has a built-in structural equality comparer already (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `Assert.AreEqual` uses `Object.Equals()` to verify the equality between the actual and the expected instance, while `Assert.AreSame` uses `Object.ReferenceEquals`.

If your class does not implement any built-in equality mechanism; for example by overriding `Object.Equals`, you will end up with the issue you describe because [MbUnit](http://gallio.org/) does not know how to compare two instances of the type under test.

There are several solutions. One of them is Coppermill's solution: you may want to implement a structural equality comparer based on reflection. But MbUnit has already a built-in [feature like that](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_StructuralEqualityComparer_1.htm). It's called `StructuralEqualityComparer<T>` and it's very easy to use. So why reinventing the wheel?

```
Assert.AreSame(RawDataRow, result, new StructuralEqualityComparer<MyDataRow>
{
   { x => x.CentreID },
   { x => x.CentreLearnerRef, (a, b) => a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) },
   { x => x.ContactID },
   // You can customize completely the comparison process...
});
```

Anyway, I suggest you read that article: http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2009/09/equality-assertions-in-mbunit-v3.html

You may also want to read [that article](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit:equality_testing) in the Gallio wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically looking for *referential equality*?  `AreSame` is testing that both references point to the same object.  From the doco:

> [`Assert.AreSame`](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreSame.htm) - Verifies that an actual value is referentially identical to some expected value.

If you are simply looking to compare that two instances of an object are logically equal, then `AreEqual` is what you need.

> [`Assert.AreEqual`](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreEqual.htm) - Verifies that an actual value equals some expected value.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I get the same result for this too

Comment: Just for reference:

Using Assert.AreEqual or Assert.AreSame returns "Remark : Both values look the same when formatted but they are distinct instances."

Answer (score 0):

In MbUnit 3 you can use StructuralEqualityComparer:

Assert.AreElementsEqual(obj1,obj2, new StructuralEqualityComparer());